# ViewPager not showing anything - android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need some advice. ViewPager showing just white page.  I have searched much, but I couldn't find solution for my case.
I tried to make simple button, but I got same output. I think it's not image problem. 
Here's my code.

```
public class IntroduceArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    String depart;
    String path;
    int num;

    CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduce_article, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        depart = getArguments().getString("depart");
        create();

        //customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    void create(){
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        path = dbHelper.getContentsPath(depart);
        num = dbHelper.getNum(depart);

        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());
        customPagerAdapter.mResources = new int[num];
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
            String uri = "@drawable/" + path + "_" + Integer.toString(i);
            int imageResource = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawabale", getActivity().getPackageName());
            customPagerAdapter.mResources[i] = imageResource;
        }
    }
}


public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context mContext;

    public int[] mResources;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item_0, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerimageView_0);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        super.startUpdate(container);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        super.finishUpdate(container);
    }
}
```

and here's xml code for ArticleFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:visibility="visible">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here's xml code for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/pagerimageView_0" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... First of all you must set the `android:layout_height` of the `ScrollView`'s child to `wrap_content`.

Second, Consider that you can't set `android:layout_height` of `ViewPager` to `wrap_content`. Unless you use a custom `ViewPager`. For Example you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34524240/3786566)

By setting `android:fillViewport` to true in `ScrollView`, The height of `ScrollView`'s Child automatically will set to `match_parent` until its height become taller than screen.

And I don't get it why you set the height of `ViewPager` to `0dp` and expect that it shows something!

Now your layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_pranet"
                android:visibility="visible">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent half of day solving it and gets that my ViewPager have the same id with another ViewPager in another module in my app, so I've simply gave it another id.

Answer (score 0):

You Have got it all wrong, use this code

```
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

       public int[] mResources;

        public NewsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int[] mResources) {
            super(fm);

            this.mNumOfTabs = mResources.length();
            this.mResources = mResources;
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ContentFragment.newInstance(mResources[position]);
        } 

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }



public class ContentFragment extends Fragment  {


    private Context context;

    private int resource_id;

    public static ContentFragment newInstance(int resourdid) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("resource_id", resourdid);
        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        resource_id   = getArguments().getInt("resource_id");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(in.newswallet.R.layout.content_row, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initalize();
    }


    private void initalize(){
        View itemView = getView();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerimageView_0);
        imageView.setImageResource(resource_id);    
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }





}
```

Comment: If you could mention as to why the OP "got it all wrong" and explain why your solution works, that would be great!

Comment: I know the way I handle mResources have some problem. But I can't understand why the extended fragment is needed. Could you help me more?

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="visible">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

try to change the **android:layout_height = "0dp"** to some value like **android:layout_height = "50dp"** or

give weight to the layout
android:layout_weight = "1"

Comment: Thanks. I soved problem.

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
```

With:

```
container.removeView((ConstraintLayout) object);
```

Comment: Ni Nico. Thanks, but be sure to add an explanation to your answers. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: oh yes sorry but i not speak english good :(