# How to wrap height of Android ViewPager2 to height of current item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

This question is for the new **ViewPager2** class.

There is a [similar question for the old ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484833/how-to-wrap-the-height-of-a-viewpager-to-the-height-of-its-current-fragment), but the solution requires extending **ViewPager**. However, ViewPager2 is final so cannot be extended.

In my situation, I have a ViewPager2 that contains three different fragments. One of these fragments is much taller than the other two, which means when you swipe to one of the shorter fragments, there is a lot of empty space. So how do I effectively wrap the ViewPager2 to the height of the current fragment?

Comment: Please post your code and screenshots

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Kimble Not yet. :-(

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385555/2914140 and https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/dl4ug3/viewpager2_with_views_having_different_heights/f4qy1e2/.

Answer (score 14):

The solution is to add the following in each fragment that is part of the `ViewPager2`:

```
override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   binding.root.requestLayout()
}
```

`binding.root` is from ViewBinding/DataBinding but it's is the main container of your layout, i.e. `ConstraintLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly this code does .. it fixes my problem but  i don't understand why

Answer (score 8):

I'm not at all happy with this workaround, but it does solve the rendering problems I had when trying to use ViewPager2 with fragments of different heights. It will obviously slow down rendering and consume more memory.

```
myStupidViewPager2.offscreenPageLimit = fragments.size
```

Comment: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` did not work for me. However, my pages are now Views (rather than Fragments), so maybe your answer could work for someone else.

Comment: where are you actually calling this?

Comment: Good idea but not working with lazy loaded items (like pagination)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, ViewPager2 was in ScrollView, which is under TabLayout. After navigating through the tabs, the height of the ScrollView became equal to the height of the maximum fragment height.
The problem was solved by transferring the ScrollView to the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to this question where i access the child through it's adapter as when you access the child at any given position rather than Zer0 index the view is null.

```
    class ViewPager2PageChangeCallback() : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            val view = (pager.adapter as pagerAdapter).getViewAtPosition(position)
            view?.let {
                updatePagerHeightForChild(view, pager)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updatePagerHeightForChild(view: View, pager: ViewPager2) {
        view.post {
            val wMeasureSpec =
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            val hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)

            if (pager.layoutParams.height != view.measuredHeight) {
                pager.layoutParams = (pager.layoutParams)
                    .also { lp ->
                        lp.height = view.measuredHeight
                    }
            }
        }
    }

   pager.offscreenPageLimit = 1            
   pagerpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(ViewPager2PageChangeCallback())

     override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        pager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(ViewPager2PageChangeCallback())
    }

 

    class OrderDetailsPager(
    private val arrayList: ArrayList<Fragment>,
    fragmentManger: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
    ) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManger, lifecycle) {
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return arrayList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    fun getViewAtPosition(position: Int): View? {
        return arrayList[position].view
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not works, what is getViewAtPosition and pagerAdapter ? Code is really bad.

Comment: getViewAtPosition as a method added at your pagerAdapter (View pager2 Adapter)

Comment: @AssemMahrous could you please update the example code to also show getViewAtPosition and pagerAdapter because I am puzzled aswell by where you got those from.

Comment: i have edited the code and adde the pager adapter @sphrak

Comment: pretty sure this doesn't work for viewpager2 

FragmentStateAdapter is for viewpager and it's already deprecated

Comment: @Fugogugo No it exists in viewpager2 in androidx.viewpager2.adapter package

Comment: Why do you again create a callback in `onDestroy`: `pager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(ViewPager2PageChangeCallback())`? Ha, it's funny.

Comment: `getViewAtPosition` may be unknown.

Comment: @AssemMahrous view.measuredHeight is always zero

Comment: @praj do you add the fragments to adapter and set of screen limit ??

Comment: @AssemMahrous Yes I have added fragments to adapter and offscreenPageLimit to 3. First time loading the view i am getting value for measuredHeight . Switching between tab value get reset to zero.

Comment: arrayList[position].view sometimes is null because the view has not be rendered yet, so the solution does not works in all cases

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after spending a lot of time, My `viewpager2` is inside a `Nesterscrollview`

```
binding.viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
binding.viewpager.isUserInputEnabled = false
binding.viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object :ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
     override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
           super.onPageSelected(position)
           val myFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f$position")
           myFragment?.view?.let { updatePagerHeightForChild(it,binding.viewpager) }
     }
})
```

```
private fun updatePagerHeightForChild(view: View, pager: ViewPager2) {
        view.post {
            val wMeasureSpec =
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            val hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)

            if (pager.layoutParams.height != view.measuredHeight) {
                pager.layoutParams = (pager.layoutParams)
                    .also { lp ->
                        lp.height = view.measuredHeight
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an issue with dynamic pages height which could change in the runtime. After page change, some of the content on the highest page is cut off.

I was able to fix that by re-measuring pager content (i.e page) and pager itself.

```
         viewPager2.setPageTransformer { page, _ ->
                val wMeasureSpec =
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(page.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
                val hMeasureSpec =
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
                page.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)
                measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)
                post {
                    adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
```

Comment: This one worked like charm with me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Lucas Nobile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4375521/lucas-nobile) I found out another way of implementing. Instead of putting the following code on the OnResume method of each affected fragment:

```
override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()
   binding.root.requestLayout()
}
```

Just add this override to the adapter of the viewPager2:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
   holder: FragmentViewHolder,
   position: Int,
   payloads: MutableList<Any>
){
   holder.itemView.requestLayout()
   super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
}
```

Obs: Code made in kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

For me set viewpager2's recyclerview layout params resolve this problem.

Try

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and set recyclerview layout params

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewPager.getChildAt(0);
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. All my ViewPager2 pages disappeared with this code. That said, my pages are Views now (rather than Fragments), so maybe your answer could work for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/safaorhan/1a541af729c7657426138d18b87d5bd4

this work for me;

Thanks this work for me ,when we want to use viewpager as Book ' pages. There are different kinds of page height. Sometimes , we need to scroll action when page is too long :3 At that time, just wrap your viewpager's item layout with NestedScroll View..

Thanks to @safaorhan

/**
* Disables the child attach listener so that inflated children with wrap_content heights can pass.
*
* This is very fragile and depends on the implementation details of [ViewPager2].
*
* @see ViewPager2.enforceChildFillListener (the removed listener)
*/

// call this method with your viewpager...

```
private fun ViewPager2.hackMatchParentCheckInViewPager() {
    (getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).clearOnChildAttachStateChangeListeners()
}
```

//View Pager

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/page_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
```

//Your Child Viewpager item

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      ....
    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so by overriding onPageSelected callback and remeasuring the current view's height.

It would look something like this:

```
mViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                mTabLayout.selectTab(mTabLayout.getTabAt(position));

 View view = mViewPagerAdapter.getViewAtPosition(position); // this is a method i have in the adapter that returns the fragment's view, by calling fragment.getview()
                if (view != null) {
                    view.post(() -> {
                        int wMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                        int hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec);
                        viewPager.getLayoutParams().height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
                        mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mTabLayout.getTabCount());
```

The layout of TabLayout and Viewpager2 looks the following (inside a NestedScrollView)

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/data_collection_tab_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                            android:id="@+id/data_collection_viewpager2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Also, please make sure all the Fragment's layout height it's wrap content.