# Android ViewPager2 not dynamically wrapping height of different sized fragments

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager2 that has different height fragments as children, the height of the children change after data is loaded

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/prospect_detail_tab_prospect" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/prospect_detail_tab_influencers" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/prospect_detail_tab_sales" />

                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I've tried a few different solutions but nothing has worked for resizing the viewpager2 if it goes back to a smaller fragment, it just stays the same height as the tallest fragment

Comment: What have you tried exactly? My first thought would be to call `requestLayout()` on the viewpager when a page changes, but I don't know how that'll work.

Comment: Please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

Comment: i did try requestLayout() on the viewpager when the page changes but that had no effect

Answer (score 14):

What happen is the ViewPager2 doesn't refresh its own height when your fragment's height changes (if you are using a RecyclerView inside for instance).

In order to solve this, we need to calculate the height when the user select the tab. This can be done using [registerOnPageChangeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2?authuser=1#registerOnPageChangeCallback(androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback)) and `onPageSelected`

```kotlin
registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position)

                    // Here we need to calculate height
                }
            })
```

Now, we need to calculate the height of the fragment. To do so, we need to access the fragment and its **root view**. This can be done using the fragmentManager provided to your ViewPagerAdapter, when creating it, e.g. here we are using childFragmentManager:
`PagerViewAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)`

```kotlin
registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)
    
        // Because the fragment might or might not be created yet, 
        // we need to check for the size of the fragmentManager 
        // before accessing it.
        if (childFragmentManager.fragments.size > position) {
            val fragment = childFragmentManager.fragments.get(position)
            fragment.view?.let {
                // Now we've got access to the fragment Root View
                // we will use it to calculate the height and 
                // apply it to the ViewPager2
                updatePagerHeightForChild(it, binding.viewPager)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```kotlin
// This function can sit in an Helper file, so it can be shared across your project.
fun updatePagerHeightForChild(view: View, pager: ViewPager2) {
    view.post {
        val wMeasureSpec =
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        val hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)

        if (pager.layoutParams.height != view.measuredHeight) {
            pager.layoutParams = (pager.layoutParams)
                    .also { lp ->
                        // applying Fragment Root View Height to
                        // the pager LayoutParams, so they match
                        lp.height = view.measuredHeight
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice: We are accessing the `viewPager` using binding, if you do not use binding, provide the viewPager your own way, maybe with `findViewById()`

**Limitation: Async Loading Content**

if you've got some dynamic loading content, you might need to couple with solution with `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`, I haven't tested that yet.

Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/143095219

Comment: Great answer, but what if I'm not using Fragments within my ViewPager2? I'm just using a RecyclerView.Adapter and a layout and ViewHolder...

Comment: similar principle applies. onPageSelected, you will need to calculate the new height. notice how the view (fragment.view?.let { ... }) is used for the calculation, you should be able to do the same with your layout.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had to do a bit extra to also call the updatePagerHeightForChild function inside my pagerAdapter when submitting the inner list to make the page size grow as items are added, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom ViewPager a little bit:

```
public class WrapHeightViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    public WrapHeightViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapHeightViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (currentPosition < getChildCount()) {
            View child = getChildAt(currentPosition);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (height != 0) {
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void measureViewPager(int currentPosition) {
        this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

After that, when init tabLayout, just call `measureViewPager(currentPosition)` in `onTabSelected` function

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.measureViewPager(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't works as your are using ViewPager (not ViewPager2) and ViewPager2  class is final (cannot be extended): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-collection-release/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java